# Is there anyway I can declare JavaScript object as a datatype in a schema?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following:

```
    public class Form
    {  
        [StringLength(500)]//change to JavaScript object
        public string FormOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

The long string that makes up a JavaScript object. The size of this string would differ depending on the size of the object so, Is there any way to change this to store a JavaScript object? Is there a datatype that allows for the storage of a JavaScript object?

```
//SOMETHING LIKE THE FOLLOWING 
    public class Form
    {  
        [JSON]
        public JSON FormOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Visual Studio? You can write the client side code in C#. This means your Javascript Object can be done using a class in C# as the Data Transfer Object (DTO).

Comment: `JObject` or `JToken` with `.HasConversion`?